# Quais as vantagens e desvantagem entre frameworks action based e component based?

Tags: mvc, arquitetura-de-software

Indiferente do framework ou linguagem(php,java,c#)

Quais as principais vantagens e desvantagem entre frameworks action based e component based?

Em que ambiente um ou o outro se encaixa melhor? Qual tipo de aplicação um tende a ser melhor que o outro?

Exemplos de aplicações se puder.

Comment: Poderia citar exemplos de frameworks aos quais se refere?

Comment: Action based = spring mvc,vraptor,slim framework, yii framework
component based = jsf,GWT, prado php

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Segundo algumas pesquisas que realizei segue alguns pontos a serem  analisados, tudo depende da necessidade do seu software:

### Action based

- Quem utiliza esta abordagem: VRaptor, Struts 2, WebWork, Grails/GSP, Play,
  Spring Web MVC
- Fácil de se realizar testes; ;
- Oferece melhor manutenção de código;
- Necessita de conhecimentos em HTML, CSS e JavaScript.

### Component based

- Quem utiliza esta abordagem: Wicket, JSF, GWT, Vaadin;
- Componentes prontos para se utilizar;
- Difícil de realizar customizações;
- Difícil de se realizar testes;
- Induz o desenvolvedor a misturar as camadas do MVC;
- Consomem mais memória;
- Abstraem a utilização do HTML, CSS e JavaScript

> Sugiro dar uma lida neste artigo (link abaixo) aonde ele aborda o
>   assunto citando alguns exemplos na prática utilizando a linguagem
>   java.
>   
> http://blog.caelum.com.br/entenda-os-mvcs-e-os-frameworks-action-e-component-based/

**OBS:** Sou programador C#

Answer (score 1):

O interessante seria a combinação destes dois paradigmas, que é o que Crux Framework nos permite através do GWT. Com ele, temos um Action Based (MVC Push) uma vez que as requisições HTTP são direcionadas exclusivamente para a manipulação de regras de negócio e não de regras de interface do front controller (que neste caso está alocado no cliente). Ao mesmo tempo, temos um Component Based (MVC Pull) porque o código do front controller é escrito em Java, as páginas são recursos xHTML (podendo conter elementos HTML puros) e são construídas através de componentes.
Em termos das vantagens e desvantagens, o nosso amigo Gustavuu respondeu muito bem.
Acrescentando, indico uma leitura [do link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22399/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-mvc-action-based-e-component-based).