# Qual a diferença entre MVC "action based" e "component based"?

Tags: mvc, arquitetura-de-software

[Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13909/7261) [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13618/7261) respode as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um, mas sem explicar qual a diferença entre eles.

Pergunto:

- Qual a diferença entre eles?
- Exemplos de *frameworks* que usam cada um deles.

*Obs.:* Deixemos de fora as vantagens/desvantagens, pois isso pode ser respondido na pergunta linkada acima

Comment: Sugiro que de uma lida a fundo [nesse link](http://blog.caelum.com.br/entenda-os-mvcs-e-os-frameworks-action-e-component-based/).
Ele foi até citado nesta resposta que você colocou como base. Porém ele detalha muito bem o que cada um faz, depois fala de suas vantagens, desvantagens e diferenças.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Frameworks *Component Based*

Frameworks *Component Based* mantém sincronia entre os estados dos *componentes* da *view* e do seu modelo de dados no lado do servidor.

Quando o usuário interage com a tela, as alterações realizadas são, em um dado momento, refletidas no modelo que fica no servidor.

No JSF, por exemplo, a "tela" é gerada por um *facelet*, que nada mais é que um XML que define quais componentes serão exibidos para o usuário e associam os valores desses componentes a um objeto (*Java Bean*) que fica no servidor. Esses componentes são então renderizados em HTML e, quando o usuário executa uma ação, o JSF atualiza os objetos no servidor.

Não encontrei uma representação visual adequada, mas algo aproximado num [artigo da Caelum sobre o tema](http://blog.caelum.com.br/entenda-os-mvcs-e-os-frameworks-action-e-component-based/):

[image: Component Based request]

Em frameworks *component based*, a *view* é responsável por mapear valores para os *beans* e para o modelo. A imagem acima ilustra a ordem de chamadas:

1. O usuário executa uma ação no sistema
2. O *front controller* do framework atualiza os componentes da *view* com o estado atual
3. O método do *Managed Bean* é chamado (usando JSF como exemplo), podendo executar alguma regra de negócio com os novos valores
4. Finalmente, o modelo do sistema é atualizado

## Frameworks *Action Based*

Já os frameworks *Action Based* não mantém necessariamente esse vínculo entre os estados do servidor e do cliente.

Isso não quer dizer que o desenvolvedor não possa armazenar estado no servidor, por exemplo, na sessão do usuário, mas que o vínculo entre o modelo e a *view* não é tão acoplado como no modelo *Component Based*.

Um framework *Action Based* geralmente irá receber diretamente requisições HTTP. Isso torna o modelo *action based* mais flexível, já que o desenvolvedor pode optar por qualquer tipo de *view* que gere uma requisição HTTP compatível.

Considere a ilustração a seguir (da mesma [fonte anterior](http://blog.caelum.com.br/entenda-os-mvcs-e-os-frameworks-action-e-component-based/)):

[image: Action based request]

O resumo dos passos da execução é:

1. O usuário executa uma ação no sistema
2. O *front controller* do framework direciona a requisição e os parâmetros para um método do *controller*
3. O *controller* lê os parâmetros necessários e executa regras de negócio que atualizam o modelo
4. O *controller* "devolve" uma *view* para o usuário

## Conclusão

Podemos dizer que os frameworks *component based* são mais centrados nas *views* (com seus componentes que mapeiam o modelo e os dados do usuário), enquanto os *action based* são mais centrados nos *controllers* (que recebem parâmetros via *request*).

Exemplos de frameworks [já estão na resposta citada na questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13909/7261).

Comment: Ótima resposta! Uma dúvida: podemos dizer que o Delphi usa MVC Component Based? No Android, nunca fui muito além de um "Hello World", mas me parece ser um caso de MVC Component Based também, correto?

Comment: @Andrey Delphi (desktop) e Android são *component based* no sentido de que são baseados em componentes. Porém, minha resposta foi focada em aplicações web. São coisas diferentes. O próprio MVC é diferente entre web e desktop, pois em aplicações desktop mudanças no *model* podem atualizar diretamente a *view*, enquanto no modelo MVC web isso (geralmente) não ocorre. Enfim, só cuidado para não misturar laranjas com maçãs porque ambas tem casca e sementes em comum.

Comment: Dá pra ver que o MVC tem várias variações... Isso até dá outra pergunta: *"Qual a diferença de MVC desktop e web?"* rsrsrs