# Qual a diferença do MVC web para MVC desktop/mobile?

Tags: mvc, arquitetura-de-software

Aparentemente o modelo MVC como é empregado na *web* (RubyOnRails, CakePHP, etc) é diferente do MVC como empregado no *desktop*/*mobile* (Delphi, Android, etc). No *desktop* ele parece ser mais acoplado à interface do que na *web*.

- Qual a diferença entre as duas variantes?
- Teoricamente é possível usar o MVC como é usado na *web* no *desktop* (criando separadamente classes de modelo, controladores e janelas). Isso é recomendável?

Comment: Diferente em quais sentidos?

Comment: @gmsantos Diferenças em suas implementações e em como se trabalha com elas. Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22399/7261

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considere a imagem:

[image: MVC]

Ela descreve o relacionamento entre as partes no modelo MVC.

Note a seta *notification*.

## MVC para desktop/mobile

Na versão **desktop/mobile** que funciona onde Modelo, Visão e Controlador ficam num mesmo ambiente é possível que o Modelo facilmente notifique a Visão de mudanças.

É, sim, recomendável seguir essa divisão. Aliás, muitas vezes é um processo de disciplina usar divisão em camadas em aplicações desktop pois facilmente pode-se burlar qualquer camada sem muitas consequências imediatas, além do caos que o código se torna ao longo do tempo.

Por exemplo, não usar um Controlador para gerenciar adequadamente as ações realizadas pelo usuário e as atualizações na Visão geralmente leva à "lógica espaguete", ou seja, aquela onde nunca se sabe devidamente qual o estado do sistema e o que pode ocorrer se o usuário tomar uma ação "inesperada".

Não irei discorrer sobre os detalhes de implementação porque não é minha especialidade e alongaria muito a resposta.

## MVC para web

Na versão **web**, devido à característica de conexão não persistente do protocolo HTTP e da maioria dos servidores web, o Modelo em geral não pode notificar à View, a não ser se uma nova requisição for feita pelo usuário ou algum agente no cliente.

Esse cenário pode mudar ao usar tecnologias como Websockets ou algum mecanismo equivalente, como no caso das notificações aqui do SO, mas é algo que, digamos, ainda foge à regra.