# Como trabalhar layouts e javascript em frameworks php

Tags: php, codeigniter, cakephp, framework

Estou fazendo um curso sobre frameworks e gostaria de saber o seguinte. O próprio nome da ferramenta já fala: ***framework PHP***

**Pergunta:** Quer dizer que a organização de layouts html e scripts baseados em bibliotecas Javascript é por conta do usuário? Ele faz ou coloca aonde bem entender seus layouts e scripts, na verdade tudo que não é PHP?

Existe lógica para se aplicar layouts e scripts js dentro de um ***framework PHP*** ou a preocupação do framework é específica ao ***PHP***?

Comment: Não entendi, você se refere ao MVC? Eu sou um dos desenvolvedores de um framework PHP chamado easyFast. http://bruunofco.github.io/easyfast/ um dos objetivos é manter o padrão de desenvolvimento das regras de negócios / organização de código. Além de implementar o ORM que facilita muito a comunicação com o banco de dados. Para o Layout (TPL/HTML, JS, CSS), tem padrões a ser seguidos mas não focamos nisso em nosso framework por exemplo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### O que é um framework

Nem todo framework são usados pra arquiteturas de softwares como o MVC, portanto o termo framework nem sempre vai se refererir ao MVC/HMVC/MVCP, etc.

O termo framework é usado pra se referir a *abstração* de códigos comuns e podem ser front-end, back-end, usados em aplicações web, mobile ou Desktop. Portanto o termo não se refere somente aos frameworks cakePHP, Laravel, asp.net-mvc, etc.

O termo Framework esta sendo usado fortemente se referindo ao cakephp, laravel, etc por causa da popularidade destes *frameworks específicos* e porque com o tempo e necessidade hoje pra acelerarmos o desenvolvimento usamos tais frameworks, pra evitarmos (mesmo que muitos usem sem saber que este é o motivo) problemas já conhecidos durante a *fase de desenvolvimento* e a *fase de manutenção*.

Então um framework pode ser usado pra construir um projeto em MVC, HMVC, REST, etc. Estas respostas devem lhe ajudar a entender melhor isto:

- [Qual é a diferença de API, biblioteca e Framework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/3635)

### O que é MVC

Frameworks como cakePHP suportam MVC, não quer dizer que você seja obrigado a seguir este padrão, pra entender o que é MVC ( e seus semelhantes :) ) leia esta resposta:

> Note que o padrão MVC veio antes da internet, portanto a resposta é mais voltada a web

- [O que é MVC(Model, View, Controller)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55490/3635)
- [Qual a diferença do MVC web para MVC desktop/mobile?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23692/3635)
- [O que é MVP e MVVM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/3635)

### Javascript e Frameworks PHP

Sobre a sua pergunta:

> Quer dizer que a organização de layouts html e scripts baseados em bibliotecas Javascript é por conta do usuário? Ele faz ou coloca aonde bem entender seus layouts e scripts, na verdade tudo que não é PHP?
>
> Existe lógica para se aplicar layouts e scripts js dentro de um framework PHP ou a preocupação do framework é específica ao PHP?

Se você entendeu a lógica do MVC em frameworks PHP como o cakephp, então sabe o que é `View`, o MVC no PHP é geralmente voltado a organização do back-end e geralmente você organiza o front-end (javascript e css) como achar melhor, no entanto eles devem se adequar aos *Views* ou então o contrário os Views devem se adequar aos .js, ou seja a comunicação incluir arquivos css e js na página é algo que esta mais na camada do View, no entanto apesar de muitos pensarem que models são abstrações do banco, isto não é totalmente verdade, os models desempenham a tarefa das *regras de negócios* e eles podem até definir **indiretamente** o js que será chamado (note que disse indiretamente).

Resumindo, a camada *View* é quem mais diretamente cuida do layout, javascript e css e é nela que você vai trabalhar isto.

Já as chamadas dos `Controllers/actions` pode ser feita pelo javascript e geralmente fazemos isso definindo rotas, no entanto o javascript chama a Rota e a Rota chama o Action, note que existe muita variação de como cada um usa o MVC, portanto nem tudo irá ser exato como cada pessoa diz.

Note que o cakephp tem bibliotecas que auxiliam no uso do javascript e layout junto aos seus Views:

- CakePHP 2 (no cakephp3 houve mudanças e a maior parte foi descontinuada)

  - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html
  - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html
  - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html
  - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html
- CakePHP 3

  - http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-css-files
  - http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-javascript-files
  - http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-inline-javascript-blocks
- Laravel Elixir

  - http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir (ajuda a carregar e processar js, sass, css, etc)

### O que é FLUX

O facebook criou algo alternativo ao MVC, ele se chama [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), isto causou alguma confusão, já que muitos *frameworks web MVC* são voltados pro *back-end*, o Flux funciona de ambos os lados e o Controller (dispatcher) dele é um controlador único que organiza as tarefas, não vou entrar muito em detalhes mas ele é um bom seguimento se quiser trabalhar de maneira a organizar o *front-end* e *back-end*  (ao menos este é o objetivo).

> Isto é uma opinião pessoal minha, independente de como o Flux é organizado, pro MVC não existe um padrão exato e se olhar bem o Flux é nada mais que um MVC com um *controlador principal* (dispatcher) o que até aonde sei já existia, só que não escrito da mesma maneira, basicamente podemos dizer que Flux é um nome mais *comercial* do *MVC do Facebook*

### Estrutura de pasta assets

É bom lembrar que não existe padrão oficial nem nada, cada um faz como se sentir melhor, no entanto um exemplo simples de organização dos arquivos .js, .css, .mp3, etc seria algo como:

```
projeto
├── .htaccess
├── Framework
│   ├── src
│   └── application
└── public
    ├── index.php
    └── assets
        ├── images
        ├── js
        ├── css
        └── media
```

Isto é apenas um exemplo básico, e você pode modificar a sua necessidade (ou entendimento).

### Conclusão

Sim, nos frameworks populares atuais pra PHP geralmente a organização do front-end é como você desejar e acredito que o intuito seja pra que você use coisas especificas pro front-end como Bootstrap e jQuery-ui.

O intuito deste frameworks MVC em php é criar rotas e Models pra melhor organizar teu projeto e de maneira mais rápida. Tenha em mente que frameworks MVC são pra facilitar o trabalho, não significa que você precisará ou deverá sempre usar frameworks prontos.

> Se notar qualquer coisa que discorda em minha resposta não hesite em comentar, opinar, realmente o assunto é um pouco extenso e fácil de confundir.