# Como utilizar jQuery na Arquitetura MVC?

Tags: jquery, mvc

Sabemos que MVC é um padrão de arquitetura de software (design pattern)
que faz uma separação de:

- Visão (Interface do usuário),
- Modelo (Regras de negócios),
- Controlador que realiza a comunicação entre os dois.

Claro que,MVC pode ser adotado como template para criar o seu proprio estilo arquitetural para solucionar algum problema mais especifico.

**Exemplo Projeto 1:**

*Diretórios :*

```
> Model
> Controller
> View
  > UX
```

**Diagrama de Execução:**

View → UX → Controller → Model

Usuário entra com dados de cadastro na View, ao enviar é passado para UX jQuery que é feita a validação das informações do lado cliente e enviado para o controller,  o controller apenas redireciona para o model que faz as validações do lado do servidor.

**Exemplo Projeto 2:**

*Diretórios :*

```
> Model
> Controller
> View
```

**Diagrama de Execução:**

View → Controller → Model

Usuário entra com dados de cadastro na View, ao enviar é passado para Controller jQuery que é feita a validação das informações do lado cliente e enviado o model que faz as validações do lado do servidor.

Quando questionei o porque de realizar esta separação as respostas foram assim:

**Projeto 1:**

jQuery é parte da interação com o usuário, portanto ele se faz presente na view.

**Projeto 2:**

jQuery realiza toda a interação mas também faz a comunicação com o model por meio do ajax.

Então minha dúvida é a seguinte, a onde vai o jQuery?
E que determinadas tarefas ele deve realizar nesta arquitetura?

Comment: não é impossível, porém você vai ter muito mais trabalho do que se tentar usar um framework que foi desenvolvido com esse propósito. Tente angular ou ember ...

Comment: UX = User Experience? Por que um diretório teria esse nome? Olha eu acho que talvez esta resposta ajude http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94525/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Quando você pega um projeto em andamento e vai tentar  entender o porque das coisas, isso pra mim é um Recurso Técnico Alternativo  Arquitetural vulgo Gambiarra.

Comment: Não entendi se você quis dizer que o MVC é a gambiarra ou outra coisa, todavia você não mencionou na pergunta que era um projeto em andamento. Assim que tiver um tempo leia ao menos a resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94525/3635 (ao menos a parte aonde esta escripo *"Javascript e Frameworks PHP"*), lá eu expliquei a separação e é valido pra varios ambientes independente da linguagem server-side, agora se não te serviu é porque o seu projeto não é web e se não é web você deve especificar na pergunta, espero que entenda as sugestões =)

Comment: Uma coisa, como eu disse UX significa "experiencia do usuário" talvez o que você queria escrever é UI (user interface).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## jQuery é View, simples assim!

jQuery é do lado do cliente, onde modificações podem ser feitas e manipulando as informações.

O próprio site do jquery diz:

> jQuery é uma maneira rápida, pequena e rica em recursos biblioteca JavaScript. Isso torna as coisas como passagem de HTML de documentos e manipulação, manipulação de eventos, animação e Ajax muito mais simples com uma API fácil de usar que funciona através de uma multiplicidade de navegadores. Com uma combinação de versatilidade e capacidade de extensão, jQuery mudou a maneira que milhões de pessoas escrever JavaScript.
> -[jQuery](https://jquery.com/) (Google Tradução)

**jQuery realiza toda a interação mas também faz a comunicação com a camada de modelos por meio do ajax.**

Se isso está ocorrendo, mesmo não sabendo como, tem algo errado em seu modelo. Qualquer requisição externa passa primeiro pela camada de controle, e o mesmo que se comunica com a camada de modelos. A requisição `Ajax` faz apenas a requisição, da mesma forma que um click em um botão `submit`, por assim dizer.

**Então minha dúvida é a seguinte, a onde vai o jQuery? E que determinadas tarefas ele deve realizar nesta arquitetura?**

jQuery vai na View para realizar **N** funções, mas em nenhuma delas ele irá se comunicar com a camada de modelos. O que você pode estar fazendo, é realizar uma requisição à um controller e o mesmo "te respondendo", mas não está "falando" diretamente com o Model.

Comment: É verdade, mas lembrando que o AngularJS é client-side também, e mesmo assim possui model, view e controller. MVC não é necessariamente um conceito de cliente-servidor, e sim um padrão de projeto

Comment: @LFZiron Concordo com você. Mas a resposta está diretamente ligada ao jQuery. Angular e jQuery são duas coisas completamente distintas.

Answer (score 2):

O jQuery foi criado para manipular DOM, ou seja, a priori ele age como parte da view. Uma boa solução para isso seria utilizar o AngularJS, Ember ou React.

Se o jQuery lhe for realmente necessário, utilize-o junto com um dos 3 frameworks acima.