# O micro-framework Flask usa a arquitetura Action Based ou Component Based?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, framework, flask

Estava [lendo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22707/27190) sobre os frameworks **Action Based** e **Component Based**. Já utilizei o Slim micro-framework e sei que ele é um framework Action Based, ou seja, mais focado nas ações, e a forma de utilizar ele segue muito este conceito.

Veja um exemplo (Slim):

```php
$app->get('/index', App\Controllers\IndexAction::class);
```

Perceba que a *ação* é dirigida para uma classe controladora.

Sendo assim, estou usando o Flask micro-framework e estou estudando sobre blueprints que consiste em dividir a aplicação em componentes, veja um pequeno exemplo:

```python
bp_autenticacao = Blueprint('autenticacao', __name__, url_prefix='/autenticacao')

@bp_autenticacao.route('/registrar', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def registrar():
    pass # Registrar usuário
```

Perceba que no flask a divisão consiste em quebrar a aplicação em views e fazer as views functions para cada view da aplicação usando o conceito de blueprints.

Essa abordagem do Flask me deixou com algumas dúvidas em relação a arquitetura Action Based e Component Based.

## Dúvidas

- O micro-framework Flask usa a arquitetura Action Based ou Component
  Based?
- O que caracteriza o Flask no caso dele usar uma das duas arquitetura, onde fica as ações ou componentes?
- Como essas arquiteturas no Flask funcionam no caso dele usa-las?

Answer (score 0):

O Flask utiliza a arquitetura Action Based. Isso pode ser notado principalmente quando você mapeia cada rota (endpoint) a uma função python. Cada rota seria uma Action.

Abaixo um exemplo de "Action" seguindo a idéia do exemplo que você postou:

```python
@app.get('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello World"
```

Arquiteturas Component Based abstraem mais a estrutura da aplicação, ou seja, elas escondem muitas coisas do deselvolvedor, tomando decisões por você.